# First tkinter program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm relatively new to the whole tkinter/python thing and I've just created the following Calculator:

```
import tkinter as tk


class theCalculator:

def __init__(self, master):
    master.wm_title("Calculator")
    master.geometry("340x350")
    master.resizable(0, 0)

    signsList = ["-","+","*","/","%"]
    #Declaring the buttons

    self.textField = tk.Entry(master, width=16, font=("Arial Bold",20))
    self.textField.place(x=40,y=50)

    self.cButton = tk.Button(master, text="C", width=14, height=2, command = lambda:cleanSpace(self))
    self.cButton.place(x=40, y=100)

    self.modButton = tk.Button(master, text="%", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:signThings(self,"%"))
    self.modButton.place(x=180, y=100)

    self.divButton = tk.Button(master, text="/", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:signThings(self,"/"))
    self.divButton.place(x=248, y=100)

    self.xButton = tk.Button(master, text="x", width=5, height=2, bg="yellow",command=lambda:signThings(self,"*"))
    self.xButton.place(x=248, y=142)

    self.minusButton = tk.Button(master, text="-", width=5, height=2, bg="yellow",command=lambda:signThings(self,"-"))
    self.minusButton.place(x=248, y=185)

    self.plusButton = tk.Button(master, text="+", width=5, height=2, bg ="yellow",command=lambda:signThings(self,"+"))
    self.plusButton.place(x=248, y=228)

    self.nineButton = tk.Button(master, text="9", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:setText(self,"9"))
    self.nineButton.place(x=40, y=142)

    self.eightButton = tk.Button(master, text="8", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:setText(self,"8"))
    self.eightButton.place(x=110, y=142)

    self.sevenButton = tk.Button(master, text="7", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:setText(self,"7"))
    self.sevenButton.place(x=180, y=142)

    self.sixButton = tk.Button(master, text="6", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:setText(self,"6"))
    self.sixButton.place(x=40, y=185)

    self.fiveButton = tk.Button(master, text="5", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:setText(self,"5"))
    self.fiveButton.place(x=110, y=185)

    self.fourButton = tk.Button(master, text="4", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:setText(self,"4"))
    self.fourButton.place(x=180, y=185)

    self.threeButton = tk.Button(master, text="3", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:setText(self,"3"))
    self.threeButton.place(x=40, y=228)

    self.twoButton = tk.Button(master, text="2", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:setText(self,"2"))
    self.twoButton.place(x=110, y=228)

    self.oneButton = tk.Button(master, text="1", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:setText(self,"1"))
    self.oneButton.place(x=180, y=228)

    self.zeroButton = tk.Button(master, text="0", width=14, height=2,command=lambda:zeroThings(self))
    self.zeroButton.place(x=40, y=271)

    self.pointButton = tk.Button(master, text=".", width=5, height=2,command=lambda:dotThings(self))
    self.pointButton.place(x=180, y=271)

    self.equalsButton = tk.Button(master, text="=", width=5, height=2, bg="yellow",command=lambda:calculate(self))
    self.equalsButton.place(x=248, y=271)

    #Declaring the methods

    def setText(self, text):

        self.textField.insert(tk.END,  text)

    def signThings(self, sign):

        theText = self.textField.get()

        if(len(theText)==0):
            print("The first character can't be a sign")
            return 0;

        if(theText[-1] in signsList):
            print("Can't have two signs one after another")
            return 0;

        if(theText[-1]=="."):
            print("Can't have a sign after .")
            return 0;

        self.textField.insert(tk.END, sign)


    def calculate(self):

        theResult = eval(self.textField.get())
        self.textField.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.textField.insert(0, str(round(theResult,4)))

    def cleanSpace(self):

        self.textField.delete(0, tk.END)

    def zeroThings(self):

        theText = self.textField.get()
        if(len(theText)==1):
            if(theText==0):
                print("Can't have two zeroes one after another")
            else:
                self.textField.insert(tk.END,"0")
        elif(len(theText)>1):
            self.textField.insert(tk.END,"0")

    def dotThings(self):

        theText = self.textField.get()
        numberOfSigns = 0
        numberOfDots = 0

        for c in theText:
            if c in signsList:
                numberOfSigns +=1
            if c==".":
                numberOfDots +=1
        try:
            if (numberOfSigns>=numberOfDots and theText[-1] not in signsList):
                self.textField.insert(tk.END,".")
        except Exception as e:
            self.textField.insert(tk.END,".")


root = tk.Tk()

calc = theCalculator(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to ask for your opinions on this and I have some questions:

1. Is there any other way I could have declared the buttons? ie using something like a for loop to create them?
2. I'm pretty sure my "self" game isn't on point. Could you give me some advice on improving it?
3. What is your advice on improving my functions' logic?

Please, point out any another flaws you see.

Thank you

Comment: If your code works, and you're looking for advice about how to improve it, you'd better ask on [codereview.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review

Comment: im sorry, i didnt know about the existence of the other site